# DB2 SQL Updating a table value

Tags: sql, db2, sql-update

I'm trying to update a table value that is initially set to 0, I'm working with DB2. However, when I go to execute my SQL I get the following error:

```
DSNT408I SQLCODE = -406, ERROR:  A CALCULATED OR DERIVED NUMERIC VALUE IS NOT
         WITHIN THE RANGE OF ITS OBJECT COLUMN                               
DSNT418I SQLSTATE   = 22003 SQLSTATE RETURN CODE
```

I understand what the error means, but I do not understand why I am getting it. Here is my SQL:

```
UPDATE INTTABLE                                      
  SET PAYMENT = DECIMAL((MONTHIRATE*OMA)/(1-POWER(1+MONTHIRATE,-420)),8,2);
```

Where PAYMENT is defined as `DECIMAL(8,2)`

Could someone please explain to me why the above UPDATE statement will not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what is happening is that the calculation you are doing is somewhere getting a result with more than 6 digits before the decimal place.

DB2 will handle having more numbers after the decimal place than you have defined in the `SCALE`, but it will error (with the `-406` you are seeing) when there are more digits than allowed with the `PRECISION` defined.

Just as an aside, do make sure you realize that a `DECIMAL(8,2)` will give you 6 places before the decimal and 2 after.

*Edit*: I think this query will show you the offending row(s):

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT 
         A.*
        ,(MONTHIRATE*OMA)/(1-POWER(1+MONTHIRATE,-420)) AS CALC
    FROM INTTABLE A
) B
WHERE CALC > 999999
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. Much appreciated